# how to delete a specifically index from Java text area

Tags: java

I have a text area like this
`JTextArea t=new JTextArea("hello world");`
and I want if the cursor is next to the letter `r` and the user presses a delete button to delete the r
so the new JTextArea be like ("hello wold")
is that possible?
I have a code that deletes the last index if the button pressed.

```
public class backspace implements ActionListener{
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int index= t.getCaretPosition();
    t.setText(t.getText().substring(0,t.getText().length() - 1));
    
    }
}
```

Comment: [`replaceRange()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#replaceRange-java.lang.String-int-int-) with an empty string, perhaps?

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. 2) Don't use set/get methods to update the text of a text component. Changes to the component should be made through the `Document` of the text component. Read the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information about Documents. The `replaceRange(...)` method mentioned above will ultimately update the Document for you. If you truly only want to remove a single character then you can create a custom Action using this approach.

Comment: 3) Swing uses `Actions` to provide functionality for a component. The ability to delete the previous/next character (ore block of characters if text is selected) is already supported by text components. If you are trying to replicate this functionality with a button, then you should use the supplied `Action`. Check out [Action Map Action](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/action-map-action/) for a helper class that allows you to associate an Action with a button. You would use:  `delete-next` and `delete-previous` as the Action names.